# New to git, pushed code to my repo and did a pull request, it was merged, but my username shows up as "Ubuntu" on the other person's page

Tags: git, github, push

I made some bug fixes to an open source project on my local machine. I pushed the code to my github account then initiated a pull request (from? for? to?) the original author of the code.

Why does my username show up as "ubuntu" on github? I did push from an Ubuntu machine, but under no circumstances do I want anyone on github to know my operating system or username. In this case both were revealed.

Why on earth did this happen and how do I prevent it?

Github says something about associating my email address with my account... I didn't push from an email address. I'm so confused.

Comment: Did you setup your name and email in Git on your local repo?

Comment: I set up a github user name but never verified an email. If I verify my email now, will the username on the author's main page change? or is it too late?

Comment: @Schleis is talking about setting things up in your repo, not on github. Check your .git/config file to see the config for that repo or check ~/.gitconfig. In those files, you should see entries for your username and email. The local config file will override the global one.

Comment: I see. So will my username change to my github display name when I change this and push/pull again? Or is it too late?

Comment: It will change for future commits, the one that you pushed will not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried updating the .gitconfig file on your system?

if not, you can use these commands to set your name and email for github to show when you commit code in the repo.

`git config --global user.email "your@email.com"`

`git config --global user.name "Your Name"`

the `--global` flag makes these settings available systemwide, so when you commit to any repo you have access to, this name shows up.

Comment: Do you know if the Ubuntu username will change to my name after I do this? Or is it too late? I'm concerned about the compromised security of my machine.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't change the names on the commits already pushed to the repo. But all new commits will have the name you specify in the above settings :)

Answer (score 2):

When you did your commit, there was probably a message that there was no Username associated with the repo.  So it used the name of your account/computer as the user that made the commit.  If you do a `git log` in your local repo, you should see `Author: Ubunut` in the commit.

You can set an Username/Email with:

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

This will set the Name and email for all the repos that you have.  If you want to change it for a specific one just drop off the `--global`

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Guarav's answer is great, but to update the name on previous commits you can use the following:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

*Edit 1 after this*

Okay - this will work ONLY on the previous commit that you have done.

So say you did a commit that had the wrong user.name and/or user.email set:

The first you would know this by doing a:

```
git log
```

and it would show the user name or e-mail as being something you did want. So now you use:

```
git config --global user.name "The Right Name"
git config --global user.email "The Right Email address"
```

So now this will be correct for future commits. But to fix the previous commit:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Will cause the user name and e-mail on the VERY LAST COMMIT to be what your current user.name and user.email are set to.

GIT has an amazing lot of functionality, and will allow you rewrite history - to the extent of even adding files that you forgot to put in a commit, and a whole bunch of things. However, this functionality comes with the price that THERE IS NOT JUST A SIMPLE PLUG AND CHUG COMMAND to
do what you want. Rewriting git history is something that takes thought -- you need to know what you are doing and why you are doing it, so I suggest that you look at some Git documentation or tutorials about it so that you can understand how to do it. Here is a link that could help:

[Git Tutorials and Training | Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git)

Comment: This didn't work, could you please explain how to change the name on my previous commits?